# Angular undefined object from http call

Tags: angular, typescript, http

I have a problem that might be easy and obvious for most of you, but I spent a lot of time on this and i decided that I need help.

I am building a simple project from frontendmentor.io and being stuck on one functionality.

So one by one:

First step of application, there is HTTP request to get data from server and display it.
I am using main component to get data and passing data down to child component as list element.
After clicking single element, there is navigation to another component with more details.
In this component, firstly I am getting parameter from url and then making another one request, but instead of full list of elements I am receiving just one element from server.

And now show must go on. My template don't show any data and I have no idea what is wrong.

data model model:

```
export interface Country {
    borders: string[];
    capital: string;
    cca3: string;
    currencies: {
        [key: string]: {
            name: string;
            symbol: string;
        }
    }
    flags: {
        alt: string;
        png: string;
        svg: string;
    };
    languages: {
        [key: string]: string;
    };
    name: {
        common: string;
        nativeName: {
            [key: string]: {
                common: string;
            }
        };
    };
    population: number;
    region: string;
    subregion: string;
    tld: string;   
}
```

service:

```
export class CountriesService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient){}

  getCountries(): Observable<Country[]> {
    return this.http.get<Country[]>('https://restcountries.com/v3.1/independent?status=true&fields=name,nativeName,population,region,subregion,capital,tld,currencies,languages,borders,flags,cca3');
  }

  getSingleCountry(countryName: string): Observable<Country> {
    return this.http.get<Country>('https://restcountries.com/v3.1/name/'+countryName+'?fullText=true&fields=name,nativeName,population,region,subregion,capital,tld,currencies,languages,borders,flags,cca3');
  }
}
```

And part of components .ts file:

```
export class CountryDetailComponent implements OnInit{
    param!: string;
    country!: Country;

    constructor(
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private cs: CountriesService
    ) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.route.params.subscribe((params) => {
            this.param = params['country'];
        });

        this.cs.getSingleCountry(this.param).subscribe(result => {
            this.country = result;
            console.log(this.country);
        });

    }
```

To display in template I am using interpolation. The weirdest thing for me is that in console object is correct, but all template is empty. I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

I have also tried to make just one request with all object's elements and keep it into a service and using a global istance of this list in whole application but I had some trouble with that and I decided to make more simple solution

EDIT:
Html component's template code:

```
<div class="country-detail content-wrapper">
<div class="container">
    <div class="button-section">
        <button (click)="returnToList()">
            <fa-icon [icon]="faArrow"></fa-icon> Back
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="details-section">
        <div class="details-section__flag">
            <img src="{{country.flags.svg}}" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="details-section__content">
            <h2>{{country.name.common}}</h2>
            <div class="details-section__content--middle">
                <div class="left">
                    <p><span class="bold">Native Name: </span>{{nativeNameArray}}</p>
                    <p><span class="bold">Population: </span>{{country.population}}</p>
                    <p><span class="bold">Region: </span>{{country.region}}</p>
                    <p><span class="bold">Sub Region: </span>{{country.subregion}}</p>
                    <p><span class="bold">Capital: </span>{{country.capital}}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="right">
                    <p><span class="bold">Top Level Domain: </span>{{country.tld}}</p>
                    <p><span class="bold">Currencies: </span>{{currencyArray}}</p>
                    <p><span class="bold">Languages: </span>{{languageArray}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="details-section__content--bottom">
                <p><span class="bold">Border Countries: </span><span class="border" *ngFor="let border of borderCountries" (click)="navigateToCountry(border)">{{border}} </span></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please dont pay attention on class names or addictional variables or functions - there were a bunch of experiments

Comment: can you share the html code

Comment: I don't see any reason why `country` wouldn't be displayed in the template... do you get any errors in the console? Could you reproduce this behavior in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? You can use an online editor such as [Stackblitz](https://www.stackblitz.com) to quickly make one!

Answer (score 2):

Normal, route event triggered after http call

Use this logic instead

```
export class CountryDetailComponent implements OnInit{
    protected country?: Country;

    constructor(
        private _activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
        private _countriesService: CountriesService
    ) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.route.params.pipe(
            map((params) => params['country']),
            switchMap((country: string) => this._countriesService.getSingleCountry(country))
        ).subscribe(country => {
            this.country = country;
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

My assumption without a repro is that you are trying to make two async calls in parallel - first, get params and then load country details.
Here are my proposed changes

1. Change template for CountryDetails (I've added async subscription)

```html
  <div class="country-detail content-wrapper">
  <div class="container" *ngIf="country$ | async as country">
      <div class="details-section">
```

2. Initialize Country based on route information

```
export class CountryDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  country$: Observable<Country>;

  constructor(
      private route: ActivatedRoute,
      private cs: CountriesService
  ) {
    this.country$ = this.route.params.pipe(
      switchMap(param => this.cs.getSingleCountry(param['country']) )
    )
  }
}
```

If it does not work, please modify this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qe1kwz?file=src%2Fmain.ts) to reproduce an issue

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all guys for help, I found solution by my own. The problem was, I received from server response with 1 element array instead of single object. The simplest thing to do was change observable type to `Country[]` in the service and assign `result[0]`.